# Modifying each element in list and then all elements in list with a funtion

Tags: python, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a list with interest rates, shown below:

```
rates = [
    -0.0005710,
    -0.001913,
]
```

I have a function that takes this list as an input and calculated different risk metrics. However, I want to first establish a baseline using this list by returning the original list. Next, I want to add **0.001** for each element in the list and then return the list back. Finally, I want to add **0.001** to all elements in the list. I would take the rates list and then return the following lists:

```
rates_adjusted = [
    -0.0005710,
    -0.001913,
]

rates_adjusted = [
    0.000429,
    -0.001913,
]

rates_adjusted = [
    -0.0005710,
    -0.000913,
]

rates_adjusted = [
    0.000429,
    -0.000913,
]
```

First I return the normal list, then I return a new list for every element in the list but adding **0.001** to one of the elements.
Would there be a way to do this in a for-loop at once? I've tried to do element-wise with a for loop using enumerate, but then I'm missing the baseline and the part where I change all elements at once.

Comment: @Sushanth This adds 0.001 to all items. I need to do this, but also add 0.001 to 1 element while keeping the others equal. For example the rates_adjusted list.

Comment: It's not clear how you got from `rates` to `rates_adjusted`. The 1st element is different, the last is the same. Can you edit the question with a (shorter) version of `rates` and an example of how you get from one to the other?

Comment: @JackFleeting I've added examples of a shorter version and all the lists I should return from the `rates` list

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in a couple of ways - here's one of them, and I'll explain as we go along:

```
rates = [-0.0005710, -0.001913,0.01034] # I modified your list by adding one element just to demonstrate
adjs = {} # create a dictionary to house the resulting lists
adjs['rates_unadjusted']=rates #first entry in the dictionary - the original list
for i in range(len(rates)):
    tmp_rates = rates.copy() #make a copy of the original list so the next iteration isn't affected
    tmp_rates[i] = tmp_rates[i] +0.001 #adjust the current list element
    adjs[f'rates_adjusted_{i+1}']  = tmp_rates # append the resulting list to the dictionary with a name reflecting its position
final = rates.copy() #now adjust all entries at once and append to the dictionary
for rate in rates:
    final[rates.index(rate)] = rate+0.001
adjs['final_rates']  = final
adjs
```

Output:

```
{'rates_unadjusted': [-0.000571, -0.001913, 0.01034],
 'rates_adjusted_1': [0.000429, -0.001913, 0.01034],
 'rates_adjusted_2': [-0.000571, -0.000913, 0.01034],
 'rates_adjusted_3': [-0.000571, -0.001913, 0.01134],
 'final_rates': [0.000429, -0.000913, 0.01134]}
```

Obviously, you can modify the output to suit your requirements.